# How to add properties to edges when using add_edge_list in graph_tool?

Tags: python, graph-tool

I am trying to use **add_edge_list** instead of inserting edges one by one using **add_edge** in order to make the graph creation faster.

But I can't find how I can create these edges at once and associate a weight property to them without looping over the edges once created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation at:

https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.Graph.add_edge_list

> If given, `eprops` specifies edge property maps that will be filled with the remaining values at each row, if there are more than two.

Comment: But  if a need to give different values for each edge do I give the properties in a list in the same order ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You just pass them in the same order.

Answer (score 12):

Adding an example usage, since the syntax is somewhat unclear from the [documentation](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.Graph.add_edge_list).

```
# the edges of the graph with corresponding properties
edges = [[x_0, y_0, p_0],
         [x_1, y_1, p_1],
         ...
         [x_n, y_n, p_n]]

# creating an external property
any_property_name = g.new_edge_property("int")

# adding list of all properties 
eprops = [any_property_name]

# add edges and properties to the graph
g.add_edge_list(edges, eprops=eprops)
```